# Inequality with parameters

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification

Let $2x(ac+bd)+2y(ad-bc)+(a^2+b^2)(1+z)+(c^2+d^2)(1-z) ≥ 0$ for any $a, b, c , d  \in  \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $x^2+y^2+z^2 ≤ 1$.

My attempt:

Take $2$ vectors: ${\vec{u}}=(a;b),{\vec{v}}=(c;d)$.

Then $a c+b d=\left(\vec{u},\vec{v}\right)\nonumber=\,u v\cos\varphi$ is a dot product of these vectors and $a d-b c=[\vec{u},\vec{v}]=u v\sin\varphi$ is a cross product of said vectors.

$\varphi$ is an oriented angle between those vectors measured from $u$ to $v$.

$$a^{2}+b^{2}=u^{2}$$

$$c^{2}+d^{2}=v^{2}$$

As a result, we get: $(1+z)u^{2}+2u v(x\cos\varphi+y\sin\varphi)+(1-z)v^{2}\geq0\forall u,v,\varphi$.

Setting $v=0$ gives $(1+z)\geq0$. Same drill gets us $1-z\geq0$.

Now if $z\ne-1$ the expression is always non-negative iff its discriminant is non-positive i.e.

$$(x\cos\varphi+y\sin\varphi)^{2}+z^{2}\leq1\forall\varphi\in[0;2\pi).$$

Note that $\operatorname*{max}(x\cos\varphi+y\sin\varphi)^{2}=\operatorname*{max}((x;y),(\cos\varphi;\sin\varphi))^{2}=x^{2}+y^{2}$. And thus $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\leq1$.

The case $z=−1$ gives us:

$$2v(u(x\cos\varphi+y\sin\varphi)+v)\geq0.$$

As we need our equation work for all values of $u,v,\varphi$ we get that

$$\begin{array}{l c r}{{}}&{{}}\\ {{x\cos\varphi+y\sin\varphi\geq-{\frac{v}{u}},u,v\neq0}}.\end{array}$$

As the right side can be made arbitrary close to zero we need to make $x\cos\varphi+y\sin\varphi\geq0\forall\varphi$, which is possible only if $x=y=0$. So in all cases $x^2+y^2+z^2≤1$.

Is my proof correct? Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: When $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$, set $\cos\varphi=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ and $\sin\varphi=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ in your inequality $(x\cos\varphi+y\sin\varphi)^{2}+z^{2}\leq 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Letting $c = 1, d = 0$, the hypothesis yields
$$2ax - 2by + (a^2 + b^2)(1+z) + 1 - z \ge 0, \quad \forall a, b\in \mathbb{R}. \tag{1}$$

From (1), clearly we have $z + 1 \ge 0$.

If $z + 1 = 0$, (1) yields
$$2ax - 2by + 2 \ge 0, \quad \forall a, b \in \mathbb{R}$$
which results in $x = y = 0$.
Thus, $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 1$.

If $z + 1 > 0$, (1) is written as: $\forall a, b \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$(z + 1)\left(a + \frac{x}{z+1}\right)^2
+ (z + 1)\left(b - \frac{y}{z+1}\right)^2 + \frac{1 - x^2 - y^2 -z^2}{z + 1}\ge 0. \tag{2}$$

From (2), we have $1 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2 \ge 0$.

We are done.